# How to handle 406 response in Selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape a website using *Selenium*. I'm able to open most of the websites. But there are some websites that give me the response **406 Not Acceptable**. Instead of receiving the actual website I only get a **406 Not Acceptable** message in the browser.

I'm currently using the following Python code (using a Mac):

```
from selenium import webdriver
DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/User123/Downloads/chromedriver 2'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://www.WEBSITE.com/')
```

I tried to open the same website with the *requests* and *beautiful soup* libraries just out of curiosity and there it worked (I didn't receive that error). Nevertheless, I need selenium for my use case due to dynamic content on the page.

I googled it but didn't find any resources that cover the selenium vs. 406 issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They might be blocking Selenium? It might not be the case but try using this driver: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thank you!